# Find column values that are shared among other column values R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following df that shows the food some people eat for a day.

```
df = data.frame("Name" = c("Brian", "Brian", "Brian",
                       "Alice", "Alice", "Alice",
                       "Paul", "Paul", "Paul",
                       "Clair", "Clair", "Clair"),
            "Meal" = c("Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner",
                       "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner",
                       "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner",
                       "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"),
            "Food" = c("Waffle", "Chicken", "Steak",
                       "Waffle", "Soup", "Steak",
                       "Waffle", "Chicken", "Chicken",
                       "Waffle", "Soup", "Chicken")
```

I want to find a food that was eaten by 100% of people, a food that was eaten by 75%  of people, and a food that was eaten by 50% of people.
In this case Waffle was eaten by everyone, chicken was eaten by 75% of people, and soup/steak was eaten by 50% of people.

EDIT:
Expected Output: The percentage of people who ate each food
Waffle - 100%
Chicken - 75%
Steak - 50%
Soup - 50%  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: With expected output explained

```
apply(aggregate(Food ~ Name, df, table)[-1],2, function(x) sum(x!=0)/length(x))*100

Food.Chicken    Food.Soup   Food.Steak  Food.Waffle 
          75           50           50          100
```

---

Old Answers

---

You should give an expected output as this question is unclear. Here is some code to rearrange your data into a form you may find more suitable for calculated statistics.

```
aggregate(Food ~ Meal, df, table)

      Meal Food.Chicken Food.Soup Food.Steak Food.Waffle
1 Breakfast            0         0          0           4
2    Dinner            2         0          2           0
3     Lunch            2         2          0           0
```

to find the most popular Food at each meal

```
Modes <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  tab <- tabulate(match(x, ux))
  ux[tab == max(tab)]
}

aggregate(Food ~ Meal, df, function(x) levels(x)[Modes(x)] )

       Meal           Food
1 Breakfast         Waffle
2    Dinner Steak, Chicken
3     Lunch  Chicken, Soup
```

[Credit for Modes Function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8189441/10442423)

Comment: I _think_ OP looks for `colMeans(with(unique(df[, c("Name", "Food")]), table(Name, Food)))`

Comment: The meal column is unimportant. The goal is to find similarities in the food people eat, and if there is a food eaten by everyone/ food eaten by most people. Regardless of the meal it was eaten at. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You still need to put an expected output.. But I've added to my answer. Hope it helps

Comment: Sorry about that, this is my first time asking a question. I've added the expected output

Comment: @markus 's answer is what I'm looking for! Marking this question as the answer even though the answer is in the comments. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If stripped to its basic structure `apply(aggregate(Food ~ Name, df, table)[-1],2, function(x) sum(x!=0)/length(x))*100` looks suspiciously like `apply(aggregate(Food ~ Name, df, function(x) ifelse(table(x) == 0, 0, 1))[-1], 2, sum)`. You could/should at least credit my answer as being a starting point for your answer.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann, looks pretty different to me. Ignoring the aggregate that has been in all my answers, apply is a common approach to col/row wise operations. Our functions(x) are totally different and have different outputs.

Comment: No it's not the use of `aggregate` or `apply`by themselves but the way they are integrated into one another that is highly similar

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann The custom function for one is in `apply` and for the other is in `aggregate` so the implementation is quite different.

Answer (score 2):

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  distinct(Name, Food) %>% 
  group_by(Food) %>% 
  summarise(WhatPercent = n() / nlevels(as.factor(.$Food))) %>%
  arrange(desc(WhatPercent)) %>%
  mutate(WhatPercent = paste0(WhatPercent * 100, "%"))


#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Food    WhatPercent
  <chr>   <chr>      
1 Waffle  100%       
2 Chicken 75%        
3 Soup    50%        
4 Steak   50%
```

Your data

```r
df <- data.frame("Name" = c("Brian", "Brian", "Brian",
                           "Alice", "Alice", "Alice",
                           "Paul", "Paul", "Paul",
                           "Clair", "Clair", "Clair"),
                "Meal" = c("Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner",
                           "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner",
                           "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner",
                           "Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"),
                "Food" = c("Waffle", "Chicken", "Steak",
                           "Waffle", "Soup", "Steak",
                           "Waffle", "Chicken", "Chicken",
                           "Waffle", "Soup", "Chicken")
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach that uses `table`:

```
x <- ((with(df, table(Food, Name)) >= 1) + 0)
## OR x <- table(unique(df[, c("Food", "Name")]))
x
#          Name
# Food      Alice Brian Clair Paul
#   Chicken     0     1     1    1
#   Soup        1     0     1    0
#   Steak       1     1     0    0
#   Waffle      1     1     1    1
rowSums(x)/ncol(x)
# Chicken    Soup   Steak  Waffle 
#    0.75    0.50    0.50    1.00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `dplyr` and `janitor`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)

df %>% 
  tabyl(Food, Name) %>% 
  mutate_if(is.numeric, ~ ifelse(. >= 1, 1, 0)) %>% 
  mutate(n = length(.) - 1) %>% 
  adorn_totals('col') %>% 
  mutate(Percent = paste0((Total - n)/n*100, "%")) %>% 
  select(Food, Percent)
```

This gives you:

```
    Food Percent
 Chicken     75%
    Soup     50%
   Steak     50%
  Waffle    100%
```

You can also change the last `select` argument to `select(-c(n, Total))` if you want to keep counts for each person:

```
    Food Alice Brian Clair Paul Percent
 Chicken     0     1     1    1     75%
    Soup     1     0     1    0     50%
   Steak     1     1     0    0     50%
  Waffle     1     1     1    1    100%
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
apply(aggregate(Food ~ Name, df, function(x) ifelse(table(x) == 0, 0, 1))[-1], 2, sum)
Food.Chicken    Food.Soup   Food.Steak  Food.Waffle 
           3            2            2            4
```

Or would you prefer this?

```
apply(aggregate(Food ~ Name, df, function(x) ifelse(table(x) == 0, 0, 1))[-1], 2, 
      function(x)  ifelse(sum(x) == length(unique(df$Name)), "100%",  
                          ifelse(sum(x) == length(unique(df$Name)) - 1, "75%",
                                 ifelse(sum(x) == length(unique(df$Name)) - 2, "50%", 
                                        ifelse(sum(x) == length(unique(df$Name)) - 3, "25%", "0%")))))
Food.Chicken    Food.Soup   Food.Steak  Food.Waffle 
       "75%"        "50%"        "50%"       "100%"
```

Comment: Just commented on the other answer, but the meal the food was eaten at is unimportant. I just want to see if there's a food that was eaten by everyone, or a food that was just eaten by most people. Regardless of the meal it was eaten at. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: That looks like a complicated version of `table(df$Food)` that gives an erroneous error for chicken. There are 4 instances of chicken.

Comment: Look at what OP says!